# How can OpenLayers 3 be forced to use new geometry on each zoom with VectorTile

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

We have features returned from the GeoJSON that [`ol.source.VectorTile`](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.source.Vector.html) consumes that have differing geometries at the varying zoom levels. When using the [`ol.layer.VectorTile`](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.layer.Vector.html) the geometry doesn't appear to update or uses the geometry provided from a different zoom level.

Is there a way to force a redraw with the feature geometry for the relative zoom level?

So far I've been messing with [`ol.style.Style`](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.style.Style.html)'s geometry parameter to see if I can get it through that but no joy as of yet.

```js
let map = map = new ol.Map({
  controls: controls,
  loadTilesWhileAnimating: true,
  loadTilesWhileInteracting: true,
  target: config.target,
  interactions: ol.interaction.defaults({
    altShiftDragRotate: false,
    pinchRotate: false
  }),
  view: config.view
});

let tileLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.XYZ({
    url: config.tileUrl,
    tilePixelRatio: 2,
    projection: config.projection
  });
});
map.addLayer(tileLayer);

let vectorLayer = new ol.layer.VectorTile({
  projection: config.projection,
  renderMode: 'vector',
  source: new ol.source.VectorTile({
    projection: config.projection,
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
    url: config.vectorUrl,
    tileGrid: ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({
      extent: config.extent
    })
  }),
  style: config.styler
});
map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
```

Comment: Could you please provide us a living example? We don't know the elements in "config"

Comment: Are you sure your `tileGrid` configuration is correct? Because the whole point of vector tiles is that different geometries are used at different zoom levels. Also double check your tiles's GeoJSON to see if you get the geometries you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Check geometry is correct. I found the data I was getting didn't have the correct geometries hence they weren't appearing where expected!